# How to include ::after in the parent elements height?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I have an element, which has a circle as a background, made with the `::after` pseudo-element. I want the parent element to include it to its height, so it **won't overlap other elements following** it. Please look at the following example:

```css
div{  
position: relative;
}

div::after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  left: 0;
}


/* NOT RELEVANT */

body{
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

div{
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  line-height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    this is the content with the after element as a background
</div>

<p>
  This is some other text: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</p>
```

As you can see, the **red circle is overlapping the paragraph** beneath it. My desired result would look like this (i added margin to the paragraph):

[image]

---

I thought about solving the problem with the `overflow` property, but it did not work for me. **How can I solve this problem?**

Comment: Since you're using a fixed `height` and `width` for the `::after`, I would just add `margin-top` to the element underneath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `p` element should have a relative positioning in order to adjust its position. The fast way is to set `position: relative;` and `top: 200px;` or whatever the height of the previous `div::after` is (in your example it has a height of 200px). To make it responsive, you can avoid using fixed units, and instead use `vh` or `rem`.

Comment: Thanks, that would work. However, the `:.after` elements height is relative to the parents div height, which is unknown in my project (the content changes and therefore the height). Is there another way?